# MYSQL INSERT syntax error with incorrect line number

Tags: php, mysql

I'm currently working on creating a login system, one part of which is of course registration. It's been going smoothly up until this point, where I'm getting an error.

I've researched this as thoroughly as I can, but I can't find the solution as it is giving me an incorrect line number.

The error I'm getting is:

```
Error: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '1' at line 1
```

My SQL query is

```
$token = (round(microtime(true) * 1000));
$query = mysql_query("INSERT INTO "
            . "`users` "
            . "(name, password, email, token) "
            . "VALUES "
            . "('$_POST[user]'"
            . ",'".hash('sha512',$_POST['pass'])."'"
            . ",'$_POST[email]'"
            . ",'$token')") or die(mysql_error());
    if (mysql_query($query) === TRUE) {
        //echo "Sucsessfuly registered! Check your email for a confirmation link.";
    } else {
        echo "Error: " . mysql_error();
    }
```

(this is *not* the first line of the file, it's the 22d)
When the code runs, even though it throws the error it still is inserting the values into the table correctly.

Also when I run the same query in phpmyadmin, it runs just fine with no errors.

I've been trying to solve this error for the last 3 hours so any help would be appreciated ;)

Comment: The line number in the SQL error refers to the line in the query, not the line in the PHP script.

Comment: Just some friendly advice, you should sanitize those post values first.  Your just asking for SQL injection.  http://php.net/manual/en/function.filter-input.php

Comment: @Barmar that is what I figured, but wasn't sure

Comment: @tier1 Ok, thanks for the advice, I'm still fairly new to PHP :)

Comment: Barmar found the error. Plus, the `1` is based on MySQL being TRUE or 1 which explains the error and the message back.

Comment: @KeithM I used to do the same thing :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're calling `mysql_query` twice: first with the SQL, and then you're using the result of the query as if it were a query. The error you're getting is because `$query` is `true`, which gets turned into `1` when treated as a string.

Either you should just set `$query` to the SQL string:

```
$query = "INSERT INTO ...";
if (mysql_query($query)) {
    ...
} else {
    ...
}
```

or you should just check the value of `$query`:

```
$query = mysql_query(...);
if ($query) {
    ...
} else {
    ...
}
```

Comment: *D'oh!* yeah, that'll do it. Nice catch.